# Form validation with EL and JSTL in a JSP page

Tags: servlets, jstl, el, jsp-tags

i am new to coding and follow a training for this, what i am trying to do
is, create some radio buttons like this

```html
<c:when  test="${vraag.vraagtype == 1}">
       <p>${vraag.vraagnummer}. ${vraag.tekst}</p>
       <div class="antwoorden"><p>
       <c:forEach items="${vraag.alternatieven}" var="alt">
         <input type="radio" name="ant${vraag.vraagnummer}" ${requestScope.ant[vraag.vraagnummer] == 'alt' ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} value="${alt}" />${alt}
       </c:forEach>
```

the problem is that on the servlet side i validate the values and if one of them is empty i return to the page and want tofill in the question that are ansered.

the problem is with  ${requestScope.ant[vraag.vraagnummer] is has to become ${ant1} or {ant3} with stands for anwser 1 or 2 depending on how many questions there has to be anwsered.

the objects are comming correctly back from the servlet becourse if i inject
${ant2} directly in the page the value is displayed.

i can't use javascript in the page, i mustto use servlet jstl and EL.

maby you has some in sights for me.

regards
Roger

Comment: Typo. You're comparing to a hardcoded string, not to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for you're response i see what you meen, i was a snippet form one of my try's

if i adjust the code it still does not work

i still think the problem is that
i recieve ant4 fomr the servlet and ${requestScope.ant[vraag.vraagnummer] is not resolved to ant4

Found it

```
<c:set var="summary" value="summary${index}" />
```

thanks for those how read this